# Looking for a counter example - Normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I ask whether there is a counter example to the following statement:

Let G be a finite group. All the subgroups of G are normal if and only if G is cyclic.

Alternatively, if this is thought to be a true statement, a proof.

Comment: For your information: groups with all subgroups normal are called [Dedekind groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me add that there are even ***non-abelian*** groups with all subgroups normal, such as [the quaternion group of order $8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).

Answer (score 2):

A subgroup of an abelian group is always a normal subgroup, since if $h\in H\leq G$ then $g^{-1}hg = g^{-1}gh=h\in H$. Thus, any non-cyclic abelian group is a counterexample to your statement, such as $\Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_2$.